# Render React component using Firestore data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, render, jsx

I'm trying to render my Guild component with data from Firestore. I put the data from Firestore into my state as an array, then when I call the component and try to render it, nothing shows. I want to believe I'm doing something very wrong here (haven't been working with React for very long), but I'm not getting any errors or warnings, so I'm not sure exactly what's happening.

**Guilds.js**

```
<Col>
    <Card>
      <CardBody>
        <CardTitle className={this.props.guildFaction}>{this.props.guildName}</CardTitle>
        <CardSubtitle>{this.props.guildServer}</CardSubtitle>
        <CardText>{this.props.guildDesc}</CardText>
      </CardBody>
    </Card>
  </Col>
```

**Render function**

```
renderCards() {
var guildComp = this.state.guilds.map(guild => {
  console.log(guild)
  return <Guilds
          key={guild.id}
          guildFaction={guild.guildFaction} 
          guildServer={guild.guildServer}
          guildName={guild.guildName} 
          guildDesc={guild.guildDesc} />
 })
return <CardDeck>{guildComp}</CardDeck>
}
```

**Fetching Firestore Data**

```
guildInfo() {
Fire.firestore().collection('guilds')
  .get().then(snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      this.setState({
        guilds: [{
          id: doc.id,
          guildDesc: doc.data().guildDesc,
          guildFaction: doc.data().guildFaction,
          guildName: doc.data().guildName,
          guildRegion: doc.data().guildRegion,
          guildServer: doc.data().guildServer
        }]
      })
      console.log(doc.data().guildName)
    })
  })
}
```

UPDATE: solved, fix is in the render function.

Comment: Can you share you code for fetching data from fire store and maybe a console log of the response?

Comment: @WilliamChou sorry I wrote this post fast, keep finding things i'm missing. it's too long to post here apparently so i have to post it in a pastebin. EDIT: https://pastebin.com/Lw4XGNJ4

Comment: Does the code ever reach the inside of the `then`? If so, is there any data in the `snapshot`? Does the `console.log()` print anything?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, it prints out the only 2 columns in the database. I can get the data, I just can't get the guild component to render

Comment: Ah OK. If the call to `setState()` is happening with the right data from the database, I'm afraid I'm not the best person to help.

Comment: where are you calling your guildInfo() function? You have to make sure that data is returned before you can use it, it may be an async problem

Comment: @gianni it's being called in componentdidmount, i thought it was an async problem but it's being called, i think i'm just not properly rendering the data.

Comment: ok, try to return null before the content, if this.state.guilds is not available:
 if(!guilds){return null}

Comment: @gianni if you look at the updated render function in my original post, the console.log returns 2 objects, which is the 2 documents in my database that were called and stored locally. maybe there's a typo somewhere? i feel like this should all work.

Comment: alright, I write an answer for a piece of code you can try...

Answer (score 0):

Well, you using state "guilds" but you update state "posts" or I miss something?

Comment: yeah that was a typo on my part, i fixed that but it still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I see few things here:

1. your component is `Guild.js`, but you are rendering `<Guilds />`
2. You are setting state to `posts`, but using `this.state.guilds` to render the components
3. You are overriding that piece of state each time to the last object in the snapshot, with the way you are mapping the Firestore data
4. you are setting the ids in the list wrong using `doc.id` instead of `doc.data().id`
5. You aren't mapping `guilds` to render. guilds is an array of guild objects, so you should do something like `guilds.map(guild => { return <Guild /> }`

These are few things to fix, and then try to `console.log(this.state.guilds)` before rendering and see if you get the right data

Comment: #1: Typo, it is actually Guilds.js in the source code //
#2: Also a typo, fixed that, nothing changed. //
#3: I have 2 documents in Firestore, they both get stored properly when called. //
#4: I use doc.id instead of doc.data().id because the id is the document id, not an id stored in the document. //
#5: I tried writing it as guilds.map(guild => {  return <Guilds /> }), and nothing happens. I could be doing it wrong considering it's not even rendering anything at all, but it works in console.log

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that because setState is async, by the time it actually sets the state `doc` is no longer defined. Try creating the array first, then call setState outside of the loop ie:

```
guildInfo() {
Fire.firestore().collection('guilds')
  .get().then(snapshot => {
     let guilds = []
     snapshot.forEach(doc => {
       guilds.push({
          id: doc.id,
          guildDesc: doc.data().guildDesc,
          guildFaction: doc.data().guildFaction,
          guildName: doc.data().guildName,
          guildRegion: doc.data().guildRegion,
          guildServer: doc.data().guildServer
       });
     })
     this.setState({guilds});
  })
}
```

Comment: I tried making this edit, nothing changed. I still get the data and no component renders. I think there's something wrong in the render function. I'm starting to think return <Guilds .../> doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a map function, and in the callback function of the setState, try to console log your state after the update:

```
guildInfo() {
  Fire.firestore().collection('guilds')
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
       const guilds = snapshot.map(doc => {
         return {
            id: doc.id,
            guildDesc: doc.data().guildDesc,
            guildFaction: doc.data().guildFaction,
            guildName: doc.data().guildName,
            guildRegion: doc.data().guildRegion,
            guildServer: doc.data().guildServer
         };
       this.setState({guilds}, () => console.log(this.state))
      })
    })     
  })
}
```

If in the console log there's a little [i] symbol near your state, it means that the state is not ready, and therefore it's am async issue. Replacing the forEach with the map function may already help though.